# Do all datastructures use arrays?

Tags: java

Do all data structures use arrays? If not, how do they store the data? I have tried to search up source code for some data structures but I could not find much information.

Comment: No. Not clear what you searched for; there are multitudes of data structure code available, e.g., multiple kinds of linked lists, trees, and maps. Few of those would use arrays (but they *could*).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html

Comment: not all: example [Linked List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

Answer (score 2):

> *"all Real Programmers know, the only useful data structure
> is the array"...* :-)

<sup>(If you have never used a floppy disk, [here](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/%7Eravenben/humor/pascal) is the whole text)</sup>

No. For example, the nodes of the balanced trees are most likely implemented by simple objects ("structs" in the C world), roughly so:

```
treeNode {
  treeNode leftChild;
  treeNode rightChild;
  treeNode parentNode;
  ...other data...
}
```

Of course they could be implemented also by arrays, but not this is the practical way to do.